# Issue on Gitlab CI authorizing NPM install of a package published on Gitlab private Package registry

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, npm-install

I'm working on a project that uses a package published into another repo package registry on gitlab.

Basically, both projects are under the same group `frontend`. The one where the package is published is `https://gitlab.com/company/frontend/design-system-package` and the one trying to use it, is located on `https://gitlab.com/company/frontend/design-system-app`

I've created a **deploy token** called `PACKAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` with `read_package_registry` as the scope.

On the other side, my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```
image: node:16.14.2

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/<projectNumber>/packages/npm/:_authToken=${PACKAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}">.npmrc
    - npm install
    - npm run build

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public

  only:
    - main
```

IDK were is the issue, but I'm getting this error about Unauthorized on CI:

```
$ npm config set -- //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXXX/packages/npm/:_authToken=${PACKAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
$ npm config set @companyName:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXXX/packages/npm/
$ npm install
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/39790545/packages/npm/@companyName/kb/-/@companyName/kb-0.0.10.tgz
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-14T20_27_58_496Z-debug-0.log
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

as a note, **I'm using the project number of the project trying to install the package**, not the one where the package is published.

Any idea on what's happening here?

I'm expecting to be able to install that dependency on the project I'm trying to build on the CI.

=========

**EDIT**

Locally, I have a `.npmrc` file and I'm able to install the package.

```
@company:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${PACKAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

I have a local variable defined on my path with the same name as the deploy token created on Gitlab.

Comment: In don't see where you publish your NPM package to the package repository. Your need to run `npm publish` command: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish

Comment: You should try installing the package from your private repo locally first. It's easier to check logs and troubleshoot. And only after it works locally, do it via a pipeline.

Comment: I forgot to mention(I'll update question) Locally I have a `.npmrc` file to authorize installation and it works fine. 

The issue happens only on CI, because I'm doing something wrong on the yaml file I guess.